# Как выбрать несколько элементов без jquery когда они разные и идут подряд?

Tags: javascript

$('#modalClose, #modalOverlay').click( function(){
});

Comment: document.querySelectorAll и в цикле обрабатывать

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это делается?

Comment: В дубликате всё написано

Comment: Что означает «когда они разнные» и в чём у вас проблема? Показанный вами селектор `'#modalClose, #modalOverlay'` можно прямо так и запихать в querySelectorAll без изменений, и всё будет работать, в дубликате показано как это сделать

Comment: О, не знала что можно вместе, спасибо большое!!)

Comment: Вот проверила, не работает. Может что то не так написала? Когда querySelector, то срабатывает только на первый аргумент.

document.querySelectorAll('#modalClose, #modalOverlay').addEventListener('click', function() { 
console.log('click')
});

Comment: Вы явно невнимательно читаете всё — и здесь в комментах, и там в дубликате мы уже по несколько раз сказали, что нужно **в цикле** обрабатывать